# Ajax response is not received before application is loaded in extjs

Tags: ajax, extjs, response

I would like to send Ajax request in launch function and based on the response to open either login window or main window.

Application.js

```
    launch: function () {

            debugger;
            
            Ext.Ajax.request({
                url: 'php/foo.php',
                params: {
                  email: 'test@gg.com',
                  password: '12345',
                },
                success: function(response, opts){console.log('OK');}, 
                failure: function(response, opts){console.log('ERROR');},  
            });     
        
            debugger;
        
            console.log('This should be printed after Ajax response (either OK/ERROR)');
        
            debugger;
```

foo.php

```
<?php
$login=$_POST['email'];
$pass=$_POST['password'];

$result = array();

echo json_encode(array(
    "success" => $pass=="123456",
    "data" => $result
));
```

But, I've noticed the response from the Ajax call is not ready before the function ends (Figure 1)

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Ajax requests are asynchronous and in the above code example, the ajax request is submitted to the server and then the program steps to the next line of code (debugger). Any action to be performed upon a successful request needs to be done inside of the success callback function.

Since this is ExtJS, one pattern I have used, is to fire a global event, something like this:

> Ext.GlobalEvents.fireEvent('applicationstart')

The main application listens for this event and that in turn opens the main application. These are other ways of doing this though.

Comment: _Any action to be performed upon a successful request needs to be done inside of the success callback function._  But, in my example that action (`console.log('OK')`) is inside the success callback function.

Comment: That is correct, and that message should be displaying in the console. Inside of that function you should then also open your application window.

Comment: Thank you, but I am still confused. What I expect (and what I would like to have) is to print **OK** (or **ERROR**) before the **This should be printed after Ajax response (either OK/ERROR)** and not after it.

Comment: As norbeq indicated, adding `async: false` will do this, but definitely not recommended. You either have to add the code into the callback functions or fire an event to handle the logic to be done after the response has been received.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by setting `async:false` to request to be `synchronous`, but this is not recommended.

Ex.

```js
Ext.Ajax.request({
    async: false,
    url: 'php/foo.php',
    params: {
        email: 'test@gg.com',
        password: '12345',
    },
    success: function(response, opts){console.log('OK');}, 
    failure: function(response, opts){console.log('ERROR');},  
});
```